# How to save multiple rows to database using for loop

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop

I'm try to save all those data to DB by using for loop and **addr_types**  have already equal to more than 1. but I got only one row in DB.
It should be insert more than one as amount of addr_types but it insert only one row.

```
use App\Models\MyModels;
use DB;

class ClientCbcAddress extends MyModels
{

        protected $table = 'address';
        //protected $fillable = ['role_id','name', 'email','username'];
        protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
        public $timestamps = false;

        private $Add_rules = [
            'country_id' => 'required',
            'province_Id' => 'required',
            'id_number_1' => 'required',
            'address_en' => 'required',
        ];

        public function SaveClientAddress($data, $id)
        {
            if (!$this->Check_validator($data, $this->Add_rules)){
                return $this->Check_validator($data, $this->Add_rules);
            }

            for ($i = 0; $i <= count($data['addr_types']) - 1; $i++) {

                $city_code = '';
                $postal_code = '';

                if (trim($data['provinces']) === 'PNH' && trim($data['country']) === 'KHM') {
                    $city_code = 'PNH';
                    $postal_code = $data['provinces'][$i];
                }

                $identification = new self();
                $identification->client_id = (int)$id;
                $identification->country_id = (int)$data['country'][$i];
                $identification->province_Id = (int)$data['provinces'][$i];
                $identification->district_id = (int)$data['district'][$i];
                $identification->commune_id = (int)$data['commune'][$i];
                $identification->village_id = (int)$data['villages'][$i];

                $identification->address_type = $data['addr_types'][$i];
                $identification->address_en = $data['address_en'][$i];
                $identification->address_kh = $data['address_kh'][$i];
                $identification->city_code = $city_code; 
                $identification->postal_code = $postal_code; 

                if($identification->save()){
                        return $identification->attributes['id'];
                }
            }
        }
}
```

DB

[image: This is Table option]

Comment: But what kind of error do you get?

Comment: There is no errors but it has inserted only one rows

Comment: Do you have any UNIQUE keys?

Comment: Anyway why did you place `SaveClientAddress` function into your model and not into a controller?

Comment: I don't want to save data in Controller it should be save in Models and Call from Controller.

Comment: I think you are doing `return $identification->attributes['id'];` after first save from the loop so  you are getting only one record in DB.

Comment: Can I use this?
 self::save([
                    [
                        'client_id'=>1,
                        'country_id'=>2],
                    [
                        'client_id'=>2,
                        'country_id'=>3],
                ]);

Comment: This one will work self::insert([
                    [
                        'client_id'=>1,
                        'country_id'=>2],
                    [
                        'client_id'=>2,
                        'country_id'=>3],
                ]);

Comment: i agree with Tiger, the return might be causing a problem, you can add the id to an array instead and return the array after the loop ends

Comment: I've testing both of this inside and outsite it still the same

Comment: try commenting the return statement in if($identification->save()) and test

Comment: It is simply LR don't allow to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    use App\Models\MyModels;
    use DB;

    class ClientCbcAddress extends MyModels
    {

            protected $table = 'address';
            //protected $fillable = ['role_id','name', 'email','username'];
            protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
            public $timestamps = false;

            private $Add_rules = [
                'country_id' => 'required',
                'province_Id' => 'required',
                'id_number_1' => 'required',
                'address_en' => 'required',
            ];

            public function SaveClientAddress($data, $id)
            {
                if (!$this->Check_validator($data, $this->Add_rules)){
                    return $this->Check_validator($data, $this->Add_rules);
                }

                $array_ids = array();
                for ($i = 0; $i <= count($data['addr_types']) - 1; $i++) {

                    $city_code = '';
                    $postal_code = '';

                    if (trim($data['provinces']) === 'PNH' && trim($data['country']) === 'KHM') {
                        $city_code = 'PNH';
                        $postal_code = $data['provinces'][$i];
                    }

                    $identification = new self();
                    $identification->client_id = (int)$id;
                    $identification->country_id = (int)$data['country'][$i];
                    $identification->province_Id = (int)$data['provinces'][$i];
                    $identification->district_id = (int)$data['district'][$i];
                    $identification->commune_id = (int)$data['commune'][$i];
                    $identification->village_id = (int)$data['villages'][$i];

                    $identification->address_type = $data['addr_types'][$i];
                    $identification->address_en = $data['address_en'][$i];
                    $identification->address_kh = $data['address_kh'][$i];
                    $identification->city_code = $city_code; 
                    $identification->postal_code = $postal_code; 

                    if($identification->save()){
                      $array_ids[$i] = $identification->attributes['id'];
                    }
                }

                return $array_ids;
            }
    }
```